# How to get decryption keys from an offline player?

Tags: windows, debugging, ollydbg, decryption, encryption

I am just starting to learn reverse engineering from lena lectures.
I have 2 encrypted sample vids and an offline player which is able to decrypt the videos and play them, is there any way,I can get the decryption method from player by reverse engineering and use it to convert the vids into normal media?
All I need is a rough guide.

Comment: Your question is vague, please include the details of the binary run it through Detect It Easy. What have you done so far? Details of the files, run it through a hex editor.

Comment: Analyze the binary in a decompiler like Ghidra or IDA and try to understand the basic data flow and what encryption algorithm is used. Using frida you can then hook certain functions at run-time to extract the key.